# How Can I Access To SolidBrush In Console Application C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, brush

I have this Code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNTHC.png)

- How can i access to SolidBrush of something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider adding reference to `System.Drawing` assembly from .Net framework into your console application. I believe `System.Drawing` assembly is not referred by default in console application project template.

Comment: i Update the Pic Take a look

Comment: What compilation error you are getting while you hover your mouse over red squiggles shown in the code editor?

Comment: that was my project error i open a new one and it's working tnx